# how do I add role and capability after I create a new user

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta, capabilities

I have a simple requirement:

```
1. create a user
2. create a role for the user
3. add capability for the role
```

First, create a new user

```
$uid = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

Second & Third, create a new role and adding capability on it

```
add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities )
```

How can I make the relationship between the role and the user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use WP_User class (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User)

It has methods: set_role, add_role, remove_role.

Example:

```
$uid = wp_insert_user($userdata);
$u = new WP_User( $uid );
add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities ); // I assume $role, $display_name, $caps are already set before
$u->set_role( $role );
```